# SVG code not displayed on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I have the following HTML code to display an SVG icon. In FF it shows up nicely, but in Chrome it doesn't show up at all.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="" height="" viewBox="0 0 100 100"  
style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve" class="svg replaced-svg" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <path style="fill:#010101;" d="M93.262,75C97.547,67.639,100,59.131,100,50c0-27.612-22.388-50-50-50S0,22.388,0,50s22.388,50,50,50  c13.807,0,26.307-5.591,35.352-14.648l-8.85-8.85C69.715,83.301,60.34,87.5,50,87.5c-20.679,0-37.5-16.821-37.5-37.5  S29.321,12.5,50,12.5S87.5,29.321,87.5,50c0,4.443-0.854,8.691-2.283,12.646L85.119,62.5H75V25.135H50c-13.807,0-25,11.193-25,25  c0,13.806,11.193,25,25,25c5.737,0,10.962-2.015,15.186-5.262C67.456,72.9,70.923,75,75,75H93.262z M62.5,43.774v6.36  c0,6.896-5.615,12.5-12.5,12.5s-12.5-5.604-12.5-12.5c0-6.897,5.615-12.5,12.5-12.5h12.5V43.774z">
</path>
</svg>
```

Can anybody help me to solve that issue, please?

Comment: The above code works just fine in my chrome. Is it really all the code or are you including that in another HTML file, for example?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wonders, the problem with the above code is that it has empty width and height values, you need to either:

- Put valid `width` and `height` values

or

- Remove `width=""` and `height=""` from the SVG

That's the reason it doesn't show in Chrome or Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting height and width to 100% using css style:

```
svg
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in css file, add this class:

```
svg {z-index: 999;position: relative;}
```

and it will be ok!

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by simply adding:

```
svg {
    display: block;
}
```